# PHP regex to get specific values between slashes in a URL

Tags: php, regex, url, pcre

I have a string which has, more or less, 2000 characters and contains URLs (a railway of urls). I want to get specific values from this URL with regex but I have no idea how to use them.

A part of the string would be like this:

```php
$string = [...]http://localhost/project/gallery/http://localhost/project/case/category#/img#/case#/http://localhost/project/case/category#/img#/case#/http://localhost/project/sitemap[...]
```

What I want is to get everything that matches **category#/img#/case#/** for every different category, image and/or case of all occurrences ***(eg: "main-category/45/main/" and "secondary-category/51/id12")***.

If **category#** is more than 1 word, it's joined with a "-" *(eg: "main-category")*.

**img#** is always a 2 to 3 digit number *(eg: "45").*

**case#** varies from plain text (joined with "-" if more than 1 word) to a 4 to 5 characters long string with the two first characters being "id" and the other 2 to 3 characters as numbers *(eg1: "main-case", eg2: "id45")*.

One thing to note, if that helps anyone, is that what I want to get is **always** after **case/**.

*I would like answers/replies that do not contain loops with substr etc.*

Comment: **This might not be a job for regexes, but for existing tools in your language of choice.**  Regexes are not a magic wand you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings. You probably want to use existing code that has already been written, tested, and debugged.

In PHP, use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.


Perl: [`URI` module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/).

Ruby: [`URI` module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html).

.NET: ['Uri' class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to match your input URI:

```
'~/case/([^/]+)/(\d{2,3})/([^/]+)/~i'
```

With matching group #1 as category, group #2 as img# and group #3 as case3

**Working demo: http://ideone.com/xrsVtf**

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I was looking for! +1 for the answer and the working demo! Why regex has to be so damn difficult?!